# understanding a simple network chart

Tags: r, igraph, tidygraph

Consider this simple example

```
mynodes_alt <- tibble(id = c(1,2,4,5),
                  mygroup = c(2,2,3,3))

myedges_alt <- tibble(from = c(1,1,4),
                  to = c(4,2,3),
                  power = c(3,3,3))

tbl_graph(nodes = mynodes_alt, edges = myedges_alt) 

# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 3 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 4 x 2 (active)
     id mygroup
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       2
2     2       2
3     4       3
4     5       3
#
# Edge Data: 3 x 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     4     3
2     1     2     3
3     4     3     3
```

As you can see, there are only 3 edges here. However, creating the network viz with `ggraph` generates a puzzling chart.

```
tbl_graph(nodes = mynodes_alt, edges = myedges_alt) %>%  
  ggraph(layout = 'grid') + 
  geom_node_point(aes(color = factor(mygroup))) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(alpha = power, label = power)) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = id), repel = TRUE) +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

What is going on?
Where does that node 5 come from? It is supposed to have no edges.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't have a `node == 3` but you have an edge `from = 4, to = 3`.

Comment: I dont know... I mean edge `1 -> 4` is not even present in the network chart. I am puzzled

Comment: you may be right after all, but then this means its a bug in tidygraph. there is no node 3, so a fifth row is added to the nodes and missing node 3 becomes node 5.

Comment: If you try `str(thegraph)`, you will see it's a list of 10 but at the 5th it throws an error, `Error in adjacent_vertices(x, i, mode = if (directed) "out" else "all") : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id`.

Comment: nice catch. so likely a bug

Comment: Yes, even when I corrected the edges tibble, and replaced 5 with 4 the error was still there. If it's a package bug you should contact the maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there is not bug at all! internally, the nodes in `tidygraph` are indexed by row order! So my ID variable is misleading.

In the edge data, the link from 1 to 4 actually means a link from  the node in the **first row to the node in the fourth row** of the node data!